# Authorization header malformed WP JWT Authentication for WP REST API

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I have managed to get the token using user and pass and now I am passing the token using this ajax call in order to create a new post , like this :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://apibind.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
            type: "POST",               
            headers: { "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
              console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and I get this error : Authorization header malformed  . Anyone knows what is wrong with the header?

Answer (score 1):

simple misstake : Bearer instead of Basic (I'm using a token based authorization)

Comment: I did try with Bearer and Basic it just not work anymore after JWT update the code. I got this error every time with my App and also with Postman -> `Error: Authorization header malformed. [jwt_auth_bad_auth_header]`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the JWT related plugins from your WordPress(for my case , it's "Simple JWT Login"). They help if you are developing mobile apps for site but they interfere with the rest api call.